# Angular 4 ngStyle background-image making the page slow. Function called indefinitely on scroll

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular CLI Project

```
  "@angular/cli": "^1.1.1",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
```

I'm using the below line to dynamically load the image from the assets folder. It's also inside ng-for

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(\'' + getPackageImage(package) + '\')'}
```

Component.ts

```
public getPackageImage(tPackage: any) {
    return this.tpService.getImageFor(tPackage);
  }
```

Service.ts

```
  public getImageFor(tPackage: TourPackage) {
    return "/assets/images/tour-packages/" + tPackage.name + "/image.jpg";
  }
```

It's properly loading the image. but the problem is if the no of image's increases the the page becomes too slow.

Whenever I scroll the `getPackageImage` called multiple times and making the ui slow. Is there any way to fix this.

If I hardcode the image url in css the page is working fine..

I have temporarily hosted it on firebase - [Firebase link for problem](https://ooty-bookings.firebaseapp.com/main/tour-packages)

Comment: In fact, this *function* `getPackageImage` will be called indefinitely. I'd suggest you to do this in component, looping through the elements once (on ngOnInit).

Comment: How do I do that? @developer033 so you are suggesting to remove [ngStyle] all together..

Comment: Loop through the elements (using for) and set a property (something like url)) in your component on `ngOnInit`... So tô can have in template something like this: `[ngStyle]="{... Package.url... }"`

Comment: @developer033 did that..Still same slowness..

Comment: could you reproduce it in plunker?

Comment: @developer033 solved the issue..Added as answer.. Seems the problem is with high resolution images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is some of the image's that I have used are 8k,4k and are resized to fit into 300 x 300 div.

That's why the page hanged.

After resizing the images the slowness is gone.

Comment: Indeed it could be **one** of the problems. The other is what I said in comments (the `function` is called indefinitely).

Answer (score 0):

as @developer033 said:

```
myImage: string;
ngOnInit() {
  this.myImage = this.tpService.getImageFor(this.tPackage);
 }
```

html:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(\'' + myImage + '\')'}
```

Comment: It's not single image..It's multiple images..it's actually inside forloop.. Tried this and still same result